# how to use first band of 3d numpy array as imaginary values for all other bands

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3d numpy array like `[[6,7,8],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` and I want to use the first "band" `[6,7,8]` as imaginary values for all other "bands". which should looks like that

```
[[6,7,8],[1+6j,2+7j,3+,8j],[1+6j,2+7j,3+8j]]
```

anybody know how that works?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4):

Usually people phrase the "first band" as the first row.

```
>>> arr = np.array([[6,7,8],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])

#First need a complex datatype.
>>> arr = arr.astype(np.complex)
>>> arr
array([[ 6.+0.j,  7.+0.j,  8.+0.j],
       [ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  3.+0.j],
       [ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j,  3.+0.j]])

# .imag and .real access the real and imaginary parts of the array.
>>> arr[1:].imag = arr[0].real
>>> arr
array([[ 6.+0.j,  7.+0.j,  8.+0.j],
       [ 1.+6.j,  2.+7.j,  3.+8.j],
       [ 1.+6.j,  2.+7.j,  3.+8.j]])
```

Skipping multiple casting calls and the vstack can save a fair amount of time:

```
arr = np.array([[6,7,8],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])

%timeit a=arr.astype(np.complex);a[1:].imag = a[0].real
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.03 µs per loop

%timeit np.vstack((arr[0,:], arr[1:,:] + arr[0,:] * 1.j))
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.2 µs per loop
```

For larger arrays:

```
arr = np.random.rand(500,500)

%timeit a=arr.astype(np.complex);a[1:].imag = a[0].real
1000 loops, best of 3: 898 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit np.vstack((arr[0,:], arr[1:,:] + arr[0,:] * 1.j))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 ms per loop
```

The difference mainly comes from the `vstack` option having to cast arr to a complex data type twice.

```
%timeit arr.astype(np.complex)
1000 loops, best of 3: 530 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

One compact solution.

```
>>> a = np.array([[6,7,8],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> np.vstack((a[0,:], a[1:,:] + a[0,:] * 1.j))
 array([[ 6.+0.j,  7.+0.j,  8.+0.j],
        [ 1.+6.j,  2.+7.j,  3.+8.j],
        [ 1.+6.j,  2.+7.j,  3.+8.j]])
```

Take into account that the new array is complex, so your first row contains complex values (with imaginary part as zero), this is because all elements in an array must be of the same type.

Comment: This can be simplified: `np.vstack((a[0], a[1:] + a[0] * 1.j))`.

Comment: Good point, normally I want to show all dimensions although is unnecessary.